# Trading technologies

Tags: endless-space

I played a multiplayer match with my friend and we built an alliance. I was able to trade my technologies with my friend, but for some reason my friend can't offer me any technologies from his tech tree. I also realized that not all technologies from my military tree were able to be traded.

Are there some restrictions with what can be traded?